# How to get a function with parameters in a hook with Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, jsx

I need to make a form through hooks using Redux.State I get like this:

```
const searchValue = useSelector(state => state.Search.searchValue);
```

How do I get a function into which I pass parameters and implement it? I tried through useDispatch (), but nothing came of it. It is necessary to make onChange for this input and also I need to get another function with parameters.

```
 <InputBase
  placeholder="Search…"
  value={searchValue}
  classes={{
    root: classes.inputRoot,
    input: classes.inputInput,
  }}
  inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//import your related action function in store
import reduxStoreActionFunction from <your store path>

const YourFunctionComponent = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    //if you want to do it by form, you should have a onSubmitFunction to handle what should be done after pressing submit button
    const handleOnSubmit = () => dispatch(reduxStoreActionFunction(searchValue))
   return (
    <>
      <Form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
        <InputBase
          placeholder="Search…"
          value={searchValue}
          classes={{
            root: classes.inputRoot,
            input: classes.inputInput,
        }}/>
        <input type="submit"/>
      </Form>
    </>
/>
   )

}
```